# iOS background download

Tags: ios, background-thread

I have an application that requires downloading large amount of data when the user logs in. I wanted to move the download portion of it to a background thread so the user can navigate the app without having to wait for the download to complete. I have tried the following methods but some of them still locks the app so user cant click on anything,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

});
```

Have also tried

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadDataThatToBeFetchedInThread:) 
                      withObject:objectArrayThatNeedToFetchData];
```

this one seems to just stop if I move between activity. Have tried moving it to the AppDelegate method but when I try to save to SQlite DB i get some error. Am i doing something wrong? Can some one please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Well, `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is going to give you the *main* thread, so that's probably not what you want.

Instead, you should obtain a background queue using:

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ ... });
```

And then, it's customary to either send out some notification, or even call back to the main thread directly to (in the UI) report success:

```
dispatch_async (dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
    // Do the download...
    // Download finishes...
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Call a UI-updating method, or similar
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Look up [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/) and [NSURLSessionDownloadTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDownloadTask_class/index.html). This is the latest and greatest from Apple.

Watch the Core Networking videos (What's New in Core Networking) from the [2015 WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2015/) and [2014 WWDC videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/).

[URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html) is also a good resource.

NSURLSession is asynchronous out of the box — which is what you're looking for.

As a bonus NSURLSessionDownloadTask makes it easy to continue the download when you app changes to background state (which is much different than a background thread). It also allows you to easily cancel and/or resume a download.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `NSURLSessionDownloadTask` class. While a different strategy than what OP is trying, it's almost certainly the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` to keep it nice and clean.

Read & Watch more:

- [NSOperation reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/)
- [NSOperationQueue reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSOperationQueue)
- [Advanced NSOperations by Dave DeLong, WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-226/)

Here's a basic setup that you can customise to fit your needs

**Disclaimer**: although it seems like a lot, it makes up for a nicer API.

First, let's define an interface to handle our API endpoints:

```
// Endpoints.swift

let api_base = "https://myserver.com/"
let api_path = "api/"

protocol EndpointGenerator {
    func URL() -> NSURL
}

extension EndpointGenerator {
    func URL() -> NSURL {
        return NSURL(string: api_base)!
    }
}

// Represents a null endpoint. It will fail.
struct NullEndpoint: EndpointGenerator { }

enum Endpoint: String, EndpointGenerator {
    case Login = "login"
    case SignUp = "signup"

    func URL() -> NSURL {
        return NSURL(string: api_base + api_path + self.rawValue)!
    }
}
```

Next, let's build our custom `NSOperation`:

```
// Operation.swift
public class Operation: NSOperation {
    public typealias Completion = Operation -> ()
    public typealias Error = NSError -> ()

    var endpoint: EndpointGenerator {
        return NullEndpoint()
    }

    var headerParams: [String:String]? {
        return nil
    }

    var requestBody: [String:AnyObject]? {
        return nil
    }

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .GET
    }

    var networkTask: NSURLSessionTask?

    var completion: Completion?
    var error: Error?
    public var parsedObject = [String:AnyObject]()

    override public init() { }

    public init(completion: Completion, error: Error) {
        self.completion = completion
        self.error = error
    }

    override public func start() {
        NSURLSessionImplementaion.execute(self)
    }

    override public func cancel() {
        networkTask?.cancel()
        networkTask = nil
    }
}
```

To be almost done, let's handle the actual queue:

```
// OperationQueue.swift
public class OperationQueue: NSOperationQueue {
        public static let internalQueue = OperationQueue()

        public static func addOperation(operation: NSOperation) {
            internalQueue.addOperation(operation)
        }

        public static func addOperations(operations: NSOperation...) {
            for operation in operations {
                addOperation(operation)
            }
        }

        public static func cancellAllOperations() {
            internalQueue.cancelAllOperations()
        }
}
```

Finally, the download part:

```
// NSURLSessionImplementation.swift
enum HTTPMethod: String {
    case POST = "POST"
    case GET = "GET"
    case PATCH = "PATCH"
}

public let OSNetworkingErrorDomain = "com.swanros.errordomain"

class NSURLSessionImplementaion {
    class func execute(operation: Operation) {
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: operation.endpoint.URL())
        if let headerParams = operation.headerParams {
            for element in headerParams {
                request.setValue(element.1, forHTTPHeaderField: element.0)
            }
        }

        if let body = operation.requestBody {
            do {
                request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(body, options: .PrettyPrinted)
            } catch {
                return
            }
        }

        request.HTTPMethod = operation.method.rawValue

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            if let e = error {
                operation.error?(e)
                return
            }

            guard let d = data else {
                operation.error?(errorWithDescription("No data"))
                return
            }

            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d, options: .MutableLeaves) as? [String:AnyObject]
                guard let j = json else {
                    operation.error?(errorWithDescription("Error parsing JSON."))
                    return
                }

                if let errorMessage = string(j, key: "error") {
                    operation.error?(errorWithDescription(errorMessage))
                    return
                }

                operation.parsedObject = j
                operation.completion?(operation)
            } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                operation.error?(jsonError)
            }
        }

        operation.networkTask = task
        task.resume()
    }
}

func errorWithDescription(desc: String) -> NSError {
    return NSError(domain: OSNetworkingErrorDomain, code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:desc])
}
```

How do you implement this? Say you want to hit the `/login` endpoint. Subclass `Operation` as follows:

```
// LogInOperation.swift
public class LogInOperation: Operation {
    override var endpoint: EndpointGenerator {
        // A nice way to represent endpoints: use enums and protocols!
        return Endpoint.Login
    }

    // The headers for this particular request. Maybe you need a token here!
    override var headerParams: [String:String]? {
        return [
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Application-Id": "bAAvLosWNeSTHrlYilysdeEYoJHUXs88"
        ]
    }

    // The HTTP request body!
    override var requestBody: [String:AnyObject]? {
        return [
            "mail": mail,
            "password": password
        ]
    }

    // .GET is default
    override var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .POST
    }

    private var mail: String
    private var password: String

    public init(mail m: String, password p: String, completion: Completion, error: Error) {
        mail = m
        password = p

        super.init(completion: completion, error: error)
    }
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
// ViewController.swift

let loginOperation = LogInOperation(
                         mail: "mail@example.com", 
                         password: "123123", 
                         completion: { op in
                             // parsedObject would be the user's info 
                             print(op.parsedObject?)
                         }, error: { error in 
                             print(error.localizedDescription)
                         }
                     )
OperationQueue.addOperation(loginOperation)
```